# Null pointer exception failure. Expects bitmap if not should load default pic

Tags: java, android, 2d-games

I'm trying to learn Android, and I decided to try a simple game with andengine.  The idea is that in the main menu you can take a pic, load a pic from external, or just use the default.  I can load the game just fine when it recieves a bitmap.  But the way I'm checking to see if the pic is present so it can decide to load the default pic must be wrong.  Looking to you guys for some help.  Thanks in advance.  Here is the chunk of code that sends the intent.

```
         Intent launchIntent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, Game.class);
     startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Here is the code that gets the intent

```
public class Game extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {
private static int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
private static int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
private ITextureRegion mBackgroundTextureRegion, mTowerTextureRegion, mRing1, mRing2, mRing3;
private Sprite mTower1, mTower2, mTower3;
private Stack mStack1, mStack2, mStack3;

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
}

@Override
protected void onCreateResources() {
    try {
        // 1 - Set up bitmap textures
        ITexture backgroundTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");    
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray());
                    return is;
                }
                else {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/tower.png");
                }
            }
        });
```

I'm fairly certain the problem is here somewhere in OnCreateResources.  Thanks again!

Also, if it makes a difference (I seriously doubt it).  The intent are launched via onClick= in the manifest

logcat:

```
08-01 02:25:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(825): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 02:25:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(825): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 02:25:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onResumeGame(BaseGameActivity.java:222)
08-01 02:25:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity$4.run(BaseGameActivity.java:373)
08-01 02:25:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-01 02:25:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-01 02:25:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 02:25:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-01 02:25:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 02:25:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 02:25:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-01 02:25:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-01 02:25:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You can know exactly where the exception is by examining your logcat.

Comment: I throws it within andengine.  I'll post the error log.

Comment: Do you see the line that says your problem is in BaseGameActivity at line 222?  what is happening there?

Comment: this.mEngine.start();   There isn't much going on in this functions, this is what is on that line